# WinUSB driver for Arduino

Tags: arduino, winusb

I'm using an Arduino to read data from the web and display it. I can easily pass the data as serial using the supplied drivers, because they identify the COM port so I can send serial to the COM port.

However, I want to use 'real' USB techniques so the device can be plugged in and out like a normal USB device. I'm looking at using [WinUSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinUSB) as the driver. However, USB is all new to me. Is there an .inf file that uses WinUSB and an Arduino (I have an Uno)?

The lack of information on this is making me think I am going about this incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that an Arduino Uno is not a genuine USB device.

It acts as a Serial to USB adapter.  Consequently USB drivers don't talk to it.

I got round this by writing a sketch which reported back what device it was when it got the correct query from the PC.

On the PC I just iterated the Serial ports and sent the query to each port.  The one that replied was the Arduino.

After that I record the port number and send serial data to the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

To learn the USB portion, maybe you could combine V-USB and the UNO?

Check out [V-USB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html).

> V-USB is a software-only implementation of a low-speed USB device for Atmel’s AVR® microcontrollers, making it possible to build USB hardware with almost any AVR® microcontroller, not requiring any additional chip.

While not necessarily Arduino, it may provide you the learning exprience you want, and let you use incorporate your UNO device.

Comment: Make sure to check V-USB license.